# I get this error when i try to use NavigationContainer in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi i am trying to learn react native and i start with a small project but now when i need to use NavigationContainer i get this error all the time [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Qgc.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignUp from './src/SignUp';
import LogIn from './src/LogIn';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="LogIn" component={LogIn} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I have tried to as blackbox, chatGpt, tabnin and find any information anywhere but i havent found nothing

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may not be thoroughly reviewing the documentation. It's necessary to install `react-native-screens`.

**#Run:**

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) This is the official guide for **React Navigation**.